# Delay during login after entering correct password in Loki

Tags: release-loki, greeter, gala

I've recently started seeing a delay (about a minute or so) after entering my password in greeter and the desktop showing up.

I filed this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-greeter/+bug/1632317 thinking it was to do with the PAM kwallet module but it appears the issue still occurs for me.

Anyone else seeing this delay during login and anything I can do to help troubleshoot?

Something to do with Gala startup maybe?

I just noticed this in my dmesg:

[  101.343635] show_signal_msg: 27 callbacks suppressed
[  101.343638] loader[1699]: segfault at 88 ip 00007f7d7cca9633 sp 00007f7d361d1008 error 4 in libgtk-3.so.0.1800.9[7f7d7cb32000+71a000]

Comment: Do you have a lot of applications at startup? It might as well be one of them.

Comment: Duh, seems to be this bug instead: https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1596377

Comment: OK after some digging around, the output of journalctl command showed the following when the delay occurred at the time of login finally happening after 90 seconds: `Oct 11 20:50:18 skybird gnome-session[2743]: gnome-session-binary[2743]: WARNING: Application 'at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop' failed to register before timeout` and renaming away in `/etc/xdg/autostart` the file to `at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop.disabled` and after a few reboots seems this issue is not occuring for me.

Comment: I have the same problem now, but there is nothing interesting in dmesg: [ 107.827133] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready [ 113.340916] vboxdrv: Found 4 processor cores [ 113.358285] vboxdrv: TSC mode is Invariant, tentative frequency 2294771026 Hz [ 113.358288] vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 5.0.32_Ubuntu (interface 0x00240000) [ 113.396343] VBoxNetFlt: Successfully started. [ 113.440206] VBoxNetAdp: Successfully started. [ 113.505181] VBoxPciLinuxInit [ 113.569007] vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered) [ 163.273450] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized [ 163.

Answer (score 5):

OK after some digging around, the output of journalctl command showed the following when the delay occurred at the time of login finally happening after 90 seconds:

`Oct 11 20:50:18 skybird gnome-session[2743]: gnome-session-binary[2743]: WARNING: Application 'at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop' failed to register before timeout`

and renaming away in `/etc/xdg/autostart` the file to `at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop.disabled` and after a few reboots seems this issue is not occurring for me.

Comment: Seems someone else had the same issue with the same workaround: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1599110/comments/17

Answer (score 0):

For me, this issue is related after installing Java. Also, sometimes when I do the apt-get update, some packages gets an error.
I uninstalled java and also removed the packages that gives me errors on apt-get.