# Desktop not loading when waking up after suspend

Tags: release-loki, suspend

i have installed elementary os loki on a lenovo 510s (intel kaby lake)
4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 18 14:10:15 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

when the computer wakes up after putting it to sleep, it asks for my user password but then only the wallpaper shows up, nothing else.
anyone experiencing the same?

thanks!
best regards.

Comment: Can you wait 10 minutes and see if it loads? By the way, are you using the beta/unstable repositories of elementary (typical if you installed the loki beta instead of the stable release)? I ask this because on my system (stable loki) i have `4.4.0-59-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP` and it's fully updated so I don't understand how else you could have  `4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP`

Comment: What's the size of your swap partition

Comment: I'm sporadically experiencing a similar issue at login after starting up: the wallpaper appears, but nothing else shows up. The problem goes away when I restart.

Comment: Potentially related: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8663/delay-during-login-after-entering-correct-password-in-loki

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to login with the guest account? If that works fine then it might be some app you have at start up. It happened to me with f.lux. Check that.